# javascript - joining text box values which are populated by select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, join, text

I have 5 text boxes (id='i1' to 'i5' with a  class="in") which are populated from the values from select dropdowns. I have this bit working:

```
document.getElementById('i1').value = '/images/'; 
document.getElementById('i2').value = 'image1'; 
document.getElementById('i3').value = 'b';  
document.getElementById('i4').value = '_black';
document.getElementById('i5').value = '.jpg'; 
etc...
```

this pushes the values to the correct text boxes :)

I then have a bit of code to join all of the boxes into a string and push it to another text box (id='i6' with a class="out"):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.in').on('input',function() {
    var allvals = $('.in').map(function() { 
        return this.value; 
    }).get().join('');
    $('.out').val( allvals );
  });
});  
</script>
```

This all works if I TYPE the info into the text boxes but my select boxes do not update the 'master string i6'

The text box 'i6' will ultimately make changes to an image path and I will then try to get

```
<img src="path" name="imageThumb">
```

to change accordingly.... If anyone can point me in the right direction, I feel that I'm perhaps close-ish, but my knowledge of Javascript isn't that great!

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: Try handle also the ``change`` event: ``$('.in').on('input change', function() {})``

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I just sussed it out :)

I replaced the javascript with :

```
<script language="javascript">
function getValues(val){
    var Val1=(document.getElementById("i1").value);
    var Val2=(document.getElementById("i2").value);
    var Val3=(document.getElementById("i3").value);
    var Val4=(document.getElementById("i4").value);
    var Val5=(document.getElementById("i5").value);

    var fullString = Val1 + Val2 + Val3 + Val4 + Val5;

    document.getElementById("i8").value = fullString;
}
</script>
```

So now I have to work out how to dynamically change the image according to the new string... if anyone can help me out with that bit, I'd be really grateful...

Comment: You didn't respond to my first comment. Why this should be an answer? What is ``i8``? It was not mentioned in your first post.